# Proof unitary matrix vector columns (and rows) are orthonormal using index notation

Tags: index-notation, unitary-matrices

A matrix $A$ is said to be unitary if it satisfies:   $AA^\dagger = A^{\dagger}A = I$

being $A^\dagger$ the conjugate transpose of $A$ and $I$ the identity matrix.

I would like to prove that the colums (rows) of the matrix $A$ form an orthonormal basis,   by using index notation if possible.

The thing is that I know how to do it with matrix notation but I struggle with index notation, so if someone could help me with it...

Comment: I tried:  $ (AA^\dagger)^i_j  = (I)^i_j ~\iff~  a^i_k(a^k_j)^\dagger = \delta^i_j$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{ij}&=(A^\dagger A)_ij\\
&=\sum_k A^{\dagger}_{ik}A_{kj}\\
&=\sum_k\overline{A_{ki}}A_{kj}\\
&=\langle a_j,a_i\rangle
\end{aligned}
$$
You should figure out what $a_i,a_j$ denote.

Comment: Thank you. Could you it withthe Einstein  upper-lower index convention?